# How to parse JSON in a Django View

Tags: python, json

I post some JSON to a view. I want to now parse the data and add it to my database.

I need to get the properties `name` and `theme` and iterate over the array `pages`. My JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "xaAX",
    "logo": "",
    "theme": "b",
    "fullSiteLink": "http://www.hello.com",
    "pages": [
        {
            "id": "1364484811734",
            "name": "Page Name",
            "type": "basic",
            "components": {
                "img": "",
                "text": ""
            }
        },

        {
            "name": "Twitter",
            "type": "twitter",
            "components": {
                "twitter": {
                    "twitter-username": "zzzz"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
def smartpage_create_ajax(request):

    if request.POST:

         # get stuff and loop over each page?

       return HttpResponse('done')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

python provides [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to encode/decode json

```
import json
json_dict = json.loads(request.POST['your_json_data'])
json_dict['pages']

[
    {
        "id": "1364484811734",
        "name": "Page Name",
        "type": "basic",
        "components": {
            "img": "",
            "text": ""
        }
    },

    {
        "name": "Twitter",
        "type": "twitter",
        "components": {
            "twitter": {
                "twitter-username": "zzzz"
            }
        }
    },

    }
]
```